# Subquotient of an object in a category

Tags: category-theory

I would like to know the definition of "subquotient" in category theory.

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories and let $F: C\to D$ be a functor. Then I want to know what it means by "an object $Y$ in $D$ is a subquotient of $F(X)$ for an object $X$ in $C$".

I checked the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subquotient) but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subobject of $A$ is a (n isomorphism class of) monomorphism(s) $f:B\to A$. A quotient is a (n isomorphism class of) epimorphism(s) $g:B\to C$. So a subquotient is a quotient of a subobject of $A$, often equivalently, a subobject of a quotient.

Regarding all the parentheses: monomorphisms $f:B\to A,f':B'\to A$ represent the same subobject if there's an isomorphism $g:B\to B'$ with $f'\circ g=f$, and dually for quotients. This is really critical, for instance, for subobjects to correspond well with subsets in the category of sets, but also could slightly obscure the basic idea.

Regarding the "often," given a quotient $g:B\to C$ of a subobject $f:B\to A$ of $A$, if there are pushouts then we get an epimorphism $g':A\to D$ by pushing out $f$ along $g$, and if $f':B\to D$ is a monomorphism then we've represented $C$ as a subobject of a quotient of $A$. In many important categories, $f'$ is guaranteed to be a monomorphism, but this is not automatic.

I don't know that there's an accepted notion of subquotient when the two possible definitions don't coincide.

Comment: You might want a quotient to be a regular epimorphism, not an epimorphism. Does $\mathbb{Q}$ feel like a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ to you?

Comment: Right, I agree. I'm not sure I could hazard an opinion as to the best choice out of (regular/extremal,strong) (mono/epi) in general, but there's no reason to exclude rings as insufficiently exact for a good definition.

Comment: So, we have a epimorphism from    $F(X)$ to $Y$ with the notation in the question? And we regard $F(X)$ is a subobject of $F(X)$ by the identity morphism?

Comment: @Snow No, you have an epimorphism from a subobject of $F(X)$ to $Y$, where the subobject is not necessarily trivial.

Comment: Ok, so there exists an object $Z$ of $D$ and monomorphism from $Z$ to $F(X)$, and we have an epimorphism from $Z$ to $Y$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, that's right.